# Exporting the Structure & contents of a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, export

So i am attempting to transform a series of position frequency matrices that look like this:

```
   $`>7`
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
V1   64    5   18    5   13    4   63
V2    7    4    5    3   55    4    8
V3   13    7    8    4   16    1   12
V4   15   83   68   88   15   90   16

$`>8`
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
V1    4   27    2    7    5
V2    2   13    1    8    2
V3    3   11    1   72    2
V4   92   49   96   13   91

$`>9`
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
V1   14   11    4    5    4   10   10
V2   18    4    4   11    3   57    5
V3   49    8    6    5    3   12    2
V4   20   77   85   78   90   21   83
```

And i would like to export all of them like this into a single file.

```
>9
   14   11    4    5    4   10   10
   18    4    4   11    3   57    5
   49    8    6    5    3   12    2
   20   77   85   78   90   21   83
```

This requires me to remove the column and row names which i can do but i cannot for the life of me get the name to stay above each dataframe and maintain the structure of each dataframe.

Thankyou In advanced -R newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide a reproducible example; so, I worked on following data-frame of mine. `list` and `sink` would do the job for you.

```
df1 <- structure(list(event.time.utc = structure(c(1471407324, 1489129025, 
                                               1480714809, 1471111613, 1472965336, 1484421419, 1475607466, 1475476528, 
                                               1473041225, 1487378311), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                  time.verify = c("15:15:24", "16:57:05", "07:40:09", "05:06:53", 
                                  "16:02:16", "05:16:59", "05:57:46", "17:35:28", "13:07:05", 
                                  "10:38:31")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("event.time.utc", 
                                                                                 "time.verify"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df2 <- df1
```

I made two data-frames. Then got rid of row and column names;

```
rownames(df1) <- NULL
rownames(df2) <- NULL
colnames(df1) <- NULL
colnames(df2) <- NULL
```

In the next step using `list` I put the data-frames after each other in a list and you can see name of each data-frame there too;

```
combined.list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

#> combined.list

#$df1
#
#1  2016-08-17 00:15:24 15:15:24
#2  2017-03-10 01:57:05 16:57:05
#3  2016-12-02 16:40:09 07:40:09
#4  2016-08-13 14:06:53 05:06:53
#5  2016-09-04 01:02:16 16:02:16
#6  2017-01-14 14:16:59 05:16:59
#7  2016-10-04 14:57:46 05:57:46
#8  2016-10-03 02:35:28 17:35:28
#9  2016-09-04 22:07:05 13:07:05
#10 2017-02-17 19:38:31 10:38:31

#$df2
#                               
#1  2016-08-17 00:15:24 15:15:24
#2  2017-03-10 01:57:05 16:57:05
#3  2016-12-02 16:40:09 07:40:09
#4  2016-08-13 14:06:53 05:06:53
#5  2016-09-04 01:02:16 16:02:16
#6  2017-01-14 14:16:59 05:16:59
#7  2016-10-04 14:57:46 05:57:46
#8  2016-10-03 02:35:28 17:35:28
#9  2016-09-04 22:07:05 13:07:05
#10 2017-02-17 19:38:31 10:38:31
```

If you want this to be exactly exported to a text file then use `sink`;

```
sink("my-example.txt")
combined.list
sink()
```

This will save the text file into your working directory (alternatively, give it the full path).

Comment: Hey man, i appreicate the response but my question is how do i export this into a .txt file whilest mainting the structure of each dataframe.

Comment: @Rnewbie check the last lines.

Comment: Thankyou so much! it works! those last 3 lines were what i needed

Comment: @Rnewbie For the sake of completeness, I would keep the whole answer as is. You're welcome.